# Can't install expo -Cli

Tags: react-native, npm

When I try to start expo It tells me to install it, But When I installed it, It shows the Installed message but again tells me to Installed it.

[image: expo cli]

Comment: Please don't post error message screenshots, post the error message text (enclosed by three backticks \`\`\`). This makes stackoverflow searchable.

Answer (score 0):

What's your output of

```
expo doctor
```

I have the feeling you have a global version AND a local version.

Here is an example

[image: expo cli multiple versions]

globally I have `5.3.1`

BUT on another project, I have `expo-cli` to the dependency on `package.json`

Comment: Output of expo doctor :

`Command 'expo' not found, did you mean:
  command 'exo' from snap exoscale-cli (v1.22.2)
  command 'expr' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
  command 'expn' from deb sendmail-base (8.15.2-18)`